# How to Customize Folding Environments in ViM Using vim-latex for Beamer

Tags: beamer, vim, vim-latex

I'm trying to configure my ViM editor to improve the folding when editing Beamer files. I have [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net) installed (using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)).

Now I'd like to customize my vim-latex; specifically, I'm trying to add the `frame` environment so that it will be folded along with the default set of folded environments.

I've added a file `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` which has (among other things):

```
" Folding environments
let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments += ',frame,'
```

According to the documentation, this is how I should be able to fold the `frame` environment, but it isn't working.

Any thoughts on how to make this happen? Has anyone had success with this before?

Comment: `let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments += 'frame'` should suffice, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented in Gerd Wachsmuth's branch of latex suite:

https://github.com/gerw/vim-latex-suite

Works quite well.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need this, I have

let g:Tex_FoldedEnvironments = ',frame'

which works.

Comment: Please explain better ....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "+" before "=" then it will work :-)

I tried this setup, but I find it easier and more structured if I just use the `\section` and `\subsection` commands to setup the document. It will become annoying to unfold frame after frame after you made a big presentation.